# GSON - Convert String case insenstive

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to read out the key value pair. But want to ensure, that the the key can be read out case-insensitve. But the value had to be case senstive! How can I do this?

I have a String like this here:

```
String json = "[\n"
            + "   {\n"
            + "      \"Id\":\"Service1\",\n"
            + "      \"Version\":\"b1\"\n"
            + "   },\n"
            + "   {\n"
            + "      \"Id\":\"TestService2\",\n"
            + "      \"Version\":\"b1\"\n"
            + "   }\n"
            + "]";
```

In Java I make this here to get a List of Maps:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Map> list = gson.fromJson(json, List.class);
```

But I want to get sure, that *id* and *version* are case-insensitive, while read out the information with Java.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println("Element: " + list.get(i).get("id"));
}
```

Some ideas to resolve that?

Comment: instead of for loop try iterator or listIterator and 
System.out.println("Element: " + list.get(i).get("id")) here use "Id"

Comment: yes, you need to pass the type to the json method...

Answer (score 1):

try passing the type instead:

```
List<Map> listFromThread =  new Gson().fromJson(string_json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map>>() { }.getType());
```

Comment: No, I am getting null value for id. System.out.println("Element: " + list.get(i).get("id")); ... when I change to upper case "Id", I am getting value. Gson version 2.6.1.

Comment: are you using the annotation @serializedname ??

Comment: No, I am just using the same code present in your post with json in original post.